# ASP.NET core Restrict access to certian pages

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core

I have some admin pages which must be extra secure e.g. accessible only by a local hostname and from a limited range of IPs. How to achieve that regarding than requests can be forged?

Comment: Make your own `AuthorizeAttribute` using `HttpContext.Request.Host`

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Comment: Don't edit an answer into the question, post a self-answer instead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Done

Comment: @chrillelundmark Answered

Answer (score 1):

I solve this via Authorization filter. It may seem to be lame but it worked for my project (hosted on IIS behind a firewall)

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var allowedHosts = "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.15";
        if (
            (allowedHosts.Contains("127.0.0.1")
            && context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() == "127.0.0.1"
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]))
            ||
            (!(context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host.Contains("localhost"))
            && !allowedHosts.Contains(context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()))
            )
        {
            log();
            context.Result =new RedirectResult("/404");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)?

Comment: please add some content from the link

Comment: @Artem Oh, I didn't think of it. Apparently it would be more elegant way. Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make an implementation like this:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class LocalHostOnlyAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    [Authorize]
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // restrict if hostname is not localhost.
        if(context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host !="localhost"){
            // return UnauthorizedAccess razor page/view if not allowed.
            context.Result = new ViewResult() {ViewName = "UnauthorizedAccess" };
        }
    }
}
```

Be warned i'm not sure if this is easily spoofable, so it might create a security risk.

Especially when your request is forwared from nginx or another reverse-proxy. The host will always be `localhost`!

Maybe check request ip equals the ip of the server (but even this i think is a small security risk).